# Swift TabBarController not correctly deallocate?

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode

I create a custom TabBarController and add a few buttons with images on them.
But i found that every time i load the TabBarController without doing anything and immediately dismiss it, the memory is increased permanently. I couldn't find any problems in my code. Please help. Thanks in advance!

```
    class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    var menuButton: UIButton!
    var announcementButton : UIButton!
    var broadcastButton: UIButton!
    var toDoListButton: UIButton!
    var plusMenuBool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let newInfo = UIImage(named: "info")!.imageResize(sizeChange: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
        self.viewControllers![0].tabBarItem.image = newInfo

        let newChat = UIImage(named: "chat")!.imageResize(sizeChange: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
        self.viewControllers![1].tabBarItem.image = newChat

        self.setupMiddleButton()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func setupMiddleButton() {
        // menuButton
        menuButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 64, height: 64))
        var menuButtonFrame = menuButton.frame
        menuButtonFrame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.height - menuButtonFrame.height
        menuButtonFrame.origin.x = self.view.bounds.width/2 - menuButtonFrame.size.width/2
        menuButton.frame = menuButtonFrame

        // announcementButton
        announcementButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44))
        var announcementButtonFrame = announcementButton.frame
        announcementButtonFrame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.height - announcementButtonFrame.height
        announcementButtonFrame.origin.x = self.view.bounds.width/2 - announcementButtonFrame.size.width/2
        announcementButton.frame = announcementButtonFrame

        self.announcementButton.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 3.5)
        announcementButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(M_PI*3/4))

        // broadcastButton
        broadcastButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44))
        var broadcastButtonFrame = broadcastButton.frame
        broadcastButtonFrame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.height - broadcastButtonFrame.height
        broadcastButtonFrame.origin.x = self.view.bounds.width/2 - broadcastButtonFrame.size.width/2
        broadcastButton.frame = broadcastButtonFrame

        self.broadcastButton.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 3.5)
        broadcastButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(M_PI))

        // toDoListButton
        toDoListButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44))
        var toDoListButtonFrame = toDoListButton.frame
        toDoListButtonFrame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.height - toDoListButtonFrame.height
        toDoListButtonFrame.origin.x = self.view.bounds.width/2 - toDoListButtonFrame.size.width/2
        toDoListButton.frame = toDoListButtonFrame

        self.toDoListButton.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 3.5)
        toDoListButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(M_PI+M_PI/4))

        // addSubView
        menuButton.layer.cornerRadius = menuButtonFrame.height/2
        announcementButton.layer.cornerRadius = announcementButtonFrame.height/2
        broadcastButton.layer.cornerRadius = announcementButtonFrame.height/2
        toDoListButton.layer.cornerRadius = announcementButtonFrame.height/2
        self.view.addSubview(menuButton)
        self.view.addSubview(announcementButton)
        self.view.addSubview(broadcastButton)
        self.view.addSubview(toDoListButton)

        menuButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "plus"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        menuButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.menuButtonAction(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        announcementButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "announcement"), for: .normal)
        announcementButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.announcementButtonAction(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        broadcastButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "broadcast"), for: .normal)
        broadcastButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.broadcastButtonAction(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        toDoListButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "toDoList"), for: .normal)
        toDoListButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.toDoListButtonAction(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the tabBarController's child viewController has a "strong" reference to its parent tabBarController. After I changed it to weak, the tabBarController is deallocated correctly!

Answer (score 2):

Check out [memory management in swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html).

> To make sure that instances don’t disappear while they are still needed, ARC tracks how many properties, constants, and variables are currently referring to each class instance. ARC will not deallocate an instance as long as at least one active reference to that instance still exists.

In short you can do one of the below things:

1. Check if the tabBar is getting deallocated. Simply dismissing does not guarantee that.
2. Even if the tabBar is deallocated, you will not see the memory decrease immediately.
3. Check if some other object is referencing the tabBar. This might cause the tabBar to hang around since ARC would think that you might need the reference.

Comment: I indeed have its child holding strong reference to it self! Changing it to weak solves the issue.

Comment: Can you mark my answer as correct if that solves your issue?